# How to migrate a C# program from SQL Server to SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows Forms program that uses SQL Server Express with basic DataGridView bindings that were created by dragging and dropping the data sources on the forms.

Now I want to use SQL Server CE instead of SQL Server.

What's the best way to do this?

I've already migrated the database to SQL Server CE.

Comment: Software development is not about dragging and dropping stuff into a designer. I suggest you get familiar with the CODE produced by the designer if you ever need to modify what it does.

Comment: I know what's going on there and the reason I sayed the binding are created by drag-n-drop is to make the question shorter. I might get to fixed it somehow but I asked here to find a neat way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your classes/functions with base ado.net classes (e.g. [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and store the connection string somewhere easy the modify (App.config).

Also take care when migrating the SQL code, although in your case, you'll probably won't have that much SQL code to change.